# Easiest way to import/export a list of cron jobs per hosting account?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have a WHM/cPanel account and each hosting account that is created requires a list of cron jobs to be entered in cPanel.

Is there an easier way to create these cron jobs each time instead of inputting each one manually into cPanel >> Cron Jobs on every new cPanel account creation?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell script and order crontab, on /scripts/postwwwacct
After each create account this scripts (/scripts/postwwwacct) insert your desire cron jobs on user cron.

man cron & man crontab

```
crontab -u user file_with_cronjobs
```

After this cron of user contents cronjobs on file_with_cronjobs

Comment: Hi Abkrim, thanks for your reply. Although not quite as simple as you sugested it did certainly point me in the right direction.  It became a liitle too hard for me trying to use the cPanel API to write a script to achieve what I wanted and too expensive for me to outsource so I'm investigating other avenues.  Thanks again though for taking the time...

Comment: You do not need the API. It's simple. When you create an account, CPanel runs if the file /scripts/postwwwacct
In this file you can put in pure bash commands for adding a default cron file for each user, with a simple replace the user.